# How To add custom Menu admin side in customer tab in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, tabs, adminmenu

How to add my module name inside the customer menu tab inside the admin panel? Whether there are any possibilities to add a menu inside the customer menu?

Answer (score 2):

I have checked and find related links to refer [link](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-tab-admin-customer-edit-page-magento-2/) more help you.

Comment: Here i want to add ui component grid inside the customer edit  tab.How can i do it??

Comment: not the same as a blog but help to how to create tab using ui component work http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-grid-into-a-custom-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-magento-2-admin/

Comment: Weather It can also use under customer tab?

Comment: yes but require same change as you want to add custom tab

Comment: why are you using ui component  for the custom tab create?

Comment: No i am using uicomponent for creating a grid under customer edit tab...

Comment: ok that's good but any reason for why using this ?

Comment: I think this is esay way  to create...If there any reference?